# How to get a diff of two integer variables with the formatting hh:mm:ss:00 in R

Tags: r, time

I have the below data frame with two time variables , I want to get the diff of these 2 variables in the below format hh:mm:ss

Example : The diff of 3000000 - 3054900 should be 00:05:49 (hh:mm:ss)

```
job_start <- c(3000000,11384800,11565400,6434100)
job_end   <- c(3054900,12091700,12102900,8232200)
data <- data.frame(job_start ,job_end)
```

I tried :

```
data$newdiff <-  data$job_end - data$job_start
data$newdiff2 <- format(strptime(data$newdiff, format="%H%M%S"), format = "%H:%M:%S")

head(data)
```

It's not giving me the expected results.How can I get the diff for these 2 variables which results of showing of real time diff. When I simply deduct these variables it is not giving me the right format hh:mm:ss.

Comment: I would suggest to use a date or time format right from the start. I mean 3000000 is not a valid date and thus the difference is quite difficult to calculate correctly.

Comment: Thanks but this is the result I am getting from my data , the data been declared as int

Comment: the fourth diff is `8232200-6434100=1798100`. What is the output  you expect ?

Comment: It should convert it to the right time format 2:20:21

Comment: I don't understand how `1798100` becomes `2:20:21`. What format does the time difference `job_end - job_start` have? You need to elaborate on the rules for turning `1798100` into `2:20:21`.

Comment: [continued] I have a feeling that whatever mapping you are trying to achieve is not unique. For example for `1798100`, from what I understand, `81` seem to be seconds; since `81 > 60` you probably want to carry over one minute to the next "minute block", leaving `21` seconds. How do you know that `81` are the seconds and not `981` or `17981`? Ditto for the "minute block"; how may digits to you associate with seconds, minutes, hours? Please edit your question to include the full expected output based on your sample data, and clearly describe the rules.

Comment: The last 2 zero digits are milliseconds. You are right if the value is >60 I need to carry it forward to min and hrs. I think I will right a function and do the calculation . If I drop the last 2 digits then the str should have 6 digits . I can padd left with zero if it’s less and then start calculating . That means I’m not using properly R functions . Thought it might be an easier way to do so .

Comment: I would try to fix the underlying data generation and would try to really save these two dates as datetime figures and then it would be really easy to use `difftime` on them.

Answer (score 1):

First off, I agree with @hannes101's comment that fixing the method that generates these pseudo-timestamps is the safer and cleaner way to go.

That aside, it's not difficult to write a parser that converts the difference between `job_end` and `job_start` into a string of format `"HH:MM:SS"`.

Here is vectorised base R approach

```
parse.time <- Vectorize(function(x) {
    idx <- rev(seq(nchar(x) - 1, 0, by = -2)[-1])
    hms <- as.integer(sapply(idx, function(i) substr(x, i, i + 1)))
    hms <- c(rep(0, 3 - length(hms)), hms)
    for (i in length(hms):(length(hms) - 1)) {
        while (hms[i] > 60) {
            hms[i] <- hms[i] - 60
            hms[i - 1] <- hms[i - 1] + 1
        }
    }
    return(sprintf("%02i:%02i:%02i", hms[1], hms[2], hms[3]))
})

parse.time(data$job_end - data$job_start)
#[1] "00:05:49" "01:11:09" "00:54:15" "02:20:21"
```

---

### Sample data

```
job_start <- c(3000000,11384800,11565400,6434100)
job_end   <- c(3054900,12091700,12102900,8232200)
data <- data.frame(job_start ,job_end)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I also came up with a solution, which should at least be a starting point. I basically just pad all strings to the same length and then extract the positions, add additional zeros and then convert it using the `lubridate` package.

```
library(data.table)
library(stringr)
library(lubridate)

dt.data <- data.table(data)
dt.data[, .(
          job_start
         , job_end
         , job.diff.hour = str_pad(str_sub(str_pad((job_end - job_start),7 , 0, side ="right"), start = -7, end = -7), width = 2, pad = "0", side = "left")
         , job.diff.minute = str_sub(str_pad((job_end - job_start),7 , 0, side = "right"), start = -6, end = -5) 
         , job.diff.second = str_sub(str_pad((job_end - job_start),7 , 0, side = "right"), start = -4, end = -3) 
         , job.diff.millisecond = str_sub(str_pad((job_end - job_start),7 , 0, side = "right"), start = -2)
         , job.diff = job_end - job_start)][, .( Duration = hms(paste(job.diff.hour
                                                           , job.diff.minute
                                                           , job.diff.second
, sep = ":"))
            )]
     Duration
1:  5H 49M 0S
2:  7H 6M 90S
3: 5H 37M 50S
4: 1H 79M 81S
```

Comment: Thank you. I’ll give it a try. I had to use sql query to get what I wanted eventually.

Comment: So you fixed the underlying procedure to produce meaningful timestamps or did you convert the integers to timestamps using SQL?